# multiprocessing pipe poll hangs

Tags: python, pipe, multiprocessing

I have 2 processes, one is the main process and one is a data generator.

I´m trying to generate data quite fast, every 100 usecs a pair of values. Since the main process has more stuff to do, the main process is telling the Generator process via a simple multiprocess pipe that it is now ready to receive a new data package.

Unfortunately the `statuspipe.poll()` statement in the generator process hangs in unregular periods for a few milliseconds. Why is that ?

Parent process which sets up the data and the statuspipe:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Pipe

    self.pipe1_parent, self.pipe1_child = Pipe(duplex=False)
    self.statuspipe_parent, self.statuspipe_child = Pipe(duplex=False)

    self.process1 = Process(target=data_generator.generate_values, args=(self.data_generator,self.pipe1_child,self.statuspipe_parent))
    self.process1.start()
```

Child process which generates the data

```
def generate_values(self,pipe1,statuspipe):
    tmpcount = 0
    self.data = np.empty((self.blocksize + 1,2), dtype=np.uint16)

    while 1:
        ValueGenerator.next(self)
        #can the data pipe be filled with next dataset ?

        if statuspipe.poll():

            self.data[tmpcount,0] = tmpcount
            self.data[tmpcount,1] = self.timestamp
            pipe1.send(self.data[0:tmpcount])
            tmpcount = 0
            msg = statuspipe.recv()
        else:
            self.data[tmpcount,0] = tmpcount
            self.data[tmpcount,1] = self.timestamp
            tmpcount = tmpcount + 1
```

I´ve already tried to set up the StatusPipe with Duplex = True and False but I do not see much a difference.

Comment: Regular OS task scheduling is happening underneath. Considering the child process is running full bore, one could expect a few milliseconds here and there. You could try upping the priority of the child process.